# Converting coordinates from a linear custom map to world coordinates lat / lon

Tags: math, coordinates, converters

I want need to convert a given point (x, y) from the in-game coordinate system (just linea without degrees) to lat/lon world coordinates -180 -> 180 / -90 -> 90

I have an image of a in-game map which has the following bounds.

```
xMin: -6001.7163085938
xMax:  2912.4174804688
yMin: -3134.458984375
yMax: 2254.9025878906
```

My scenario is:

I get player coordinates which is a point within the bounds above, then i want to display this point within kibana's map feature.

In order to use the game map in kibana, i had to convert it to a geotiff which i did with gdal commands:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -105 45 105 -45 source.jpg result.tiff
gdal_warp -t_srs EPSG:4326 result.tiff end_result.tiff
```

which resizes this somehow like a stretched world (how images of our world is common), so basically it is shrinked at y-axis and stretched at x-axis.

So I assume i can not just check a left bottom and a right top point of both sizes (geotiff and original) to calculate the position, due the fact lat / lon has this degree and the game coords hasn't it.

My Question is, how i can get the lat / lon of my coordinates.

I already tried this function

```
function convertCoordinatesToLatLon(x, y) {
  var maxX = 8914.1337890626;
  var maxY = 5389.3615722655995;

  var lat = (y / maxY) * 180 - 90;
  var lon = (x / maxX) * 360 - 180;

  return { lat: lat, lon: lon };
}
```

which doesn't worked.

anybody can help?

Regards,
PrDatur

Comment: "which doesn't worked." deserves more details.  What happened?  What was hoped for?

Comment: the result were incorrect, instead of something near lon 19 and lat 4 for x = 100, y= 100 it returns `{lat: -86.66008677305481, lon: -175.96146963329505}`